# What is corresponding method to StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty() but for LocalDate?

Tags: java

```
private ClientIdentifier(final Client client, final CodeValue documentType, 
                         final String documentKey, final LocalDate validity, 
                         final String description) {
    this.client = client;
    this.documentType = documentType;
    this.documentKey = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(documentKey, null);
    this.validity = LocaleUtils.defaultIfEmpty(validity,null); // I am confused in this part
    this.description = StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(description, null);
}
```

I am passing LocalDate but don't know which utility to use for checking defualtIfEmpty

Answer (score 0):

To provide default values for any type, you can use e.g. [ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(T...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull(T...)) from Apache Commons or [MoreObjects.firstNonNull(T,T)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T)) from Guava.

Answer (score -1):

With my case there was no way to check empty dates , but you can still do that using this method that I finally thought of sharing with anyone who gets lost in the java world

1. First check if the localDate is null using the LocalDate.parse methods example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626114/checking-if-localdatetime-is-null-in-a-conditional#:~:text=A%20simple%20if%20(dateSentFormatted%20!%3D,it%20still%20sometimes%20the%20clearest.
2. Then decide what you wish to do either by creating a new object or instantiate for the date that you might want to specify like say today's date or depending on your use case.

Thanks