# Checking if LocalDateTIme is null in a conditional

Tags: java, if-statement, kotlin, logic, java-time

Here I have a function that formats a string to a LocalDateTime and returns it.

```
val dateSentFormatted = timeFormatted(record.data.dateTime);
```

```
private fun timeFormatted(dateEmailSent: String?): LocalDateTime {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateEmailSent, formatter);
}
```

My question is I wanted an if statement to run on it elsewhere in my file to check whether it's null as in:

```
if (!dateSentFormatted != null ) {

}
```

But it doesn't like that, how else can I check whether a variable of type LocalDateTime is empty in an if statement?

Comment: What do you want to say when you write `!dateSentFormatted != null`? Perhaps `!(dateSentFormatted != null)` (more easily written with `==`), or something else? (`(!dateSentFormatted) != null` would be invalid because `!dateSentFormatted` can only be a `boolean`, and that's never null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)` of the `java.time.LocalDateTime` class does not accept `null` as the character sequence (first parameter), so you have to make an explicit `null`-check and rewrite the return from your function as

```kotlin
return if (dateEmailSent != null) LocalDateTime.parse(dateEmailSent, formatter) else null
```

(you don't have to have semicolons (`;`) by the way)

Moreover, the return type of your function as written is non-nullable, so you'll have to change it to `LocalDateTime?`.

And, since there is no point in creating a parser/formatter if it is not going to be used in case of `dateEmailSent` being `null`, I suggest to rewrite the entire function as follows:

```kotlin
fun timeFormatted(dateEmailSent: String?) = if (dateEmailSent != null) {
    LocalDateTime.parse(dateEmailSent, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss"))
} else null
```

The last part is up to you, the rest is pretty much mandatory if you want to achieve the functionality you described in your question.

Comment: thank you this was the clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dateSentFormatted` is a variable of type `LocalDateTime`, you can check if it's null:

```
if (dateSentFormatted != null ) {
    // dateSentFormatted is not null
}
```

You don't need the first `!`.

Answer (score 1):

As written, `dateSentFormatted` *can't* be null: you're setting it to the return from `timeFormatted()`, which returns a `LocalDateTime`, which is not nullable.  (Unlike `LocalDateTime?`, which would be.)

And because you haven't specified its type, the compiler infers `LocalDateTime` (so even if it were a `var`, it could still never be null).

So as written, there's no point in checking for null, and your IDE will warn you that the check's pointless!

However, if it *were* nullable, then there are various options for null-checking, depending on what you want to do with it:

- A simple `if (dateSentFormatted != null)` test, as per your code (but without the extraneous `!`).  This is the traditional way, and it still sometimes the clearest.
- Other `if ()` tests.  Kotlin's standard library provides a few ways to make null checks more concise and/or more readable, e.g.:

  ```
  if (someString.isNullOrEmpty())
      // …
  ```
- The elvis operator [`?:`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator), which yields its left-hand side if that's not null, else its right-hand side.  This is useful for supplying a default/fallback value if one's not specified, e.g.:

  ```
  someFunctionCall(dateSentFormatted ?: LocalDateTime.now())
  ```

  which means roughly the same as:

  ```
  someFunctionCall(if (dateSentFormatted != null) dateSentFormatted else LocalDateTime.now())
  ```
- The safe-call operator [`?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls), which calls a method/getter only if the LHS is not null, else it gives null directly.  This is useful when following an object chain, e.g.:

  ```
  val postcode = employee?.manager?.address?.postcode
  ```

  which means roughly the same as:

  ```
  val postcode = if (employee == null)
      null
  else if (employee.manager == null)
      null
  else if (employee.manager.address == null)
      null
  else
      employee.manager.address.postcode
  ```

  …except that it won't fail if any of those objects get updated at the same time.
- The non-null assertion operator [`!!`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator).  If are sure that the value can't be null at this point, this operator tells the compiler that you know better.  (If you're wrong, you'll get a runtime exception.)  For example:

  ```
  someFunctionCall(dateSentFormatted!!)
  ```

  The potential for runtime errors means that this is rarely a good choice (which is why they made it look scary).
- Something more complex, depending on what you're trying to do…